# firebase pushnotification function topic name

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to configure the index.js file in javascript for push notifications for firebase iOS. here is my code in question:

```js
exports.newsFRA = functions.database
.ref('news/FRA/{uid}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  let newsItemFRA = snapshot.val()
  sendNotificationFRA(newsItemFRA)
})

function sendNotificationFRA(newsItemFRA) {
  let title = newsItemFRA.title
  let message = newsItemFRA.message

  let payload = {
    notification: {
      title: 'FRA News',
      body: title,
      sound: 'default'
    }
  }

  console.log(payload)
  let topic = 'FRA'

  admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)

}

exports.newsLHR = functions.database
.ref('news/LHR/{uid}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  let newsItemLHR = snapshot.val()
  sendNotificationLHR(newsItemLHR)
})

function sendNotificationLHR(newsItemLHR) {
  let title = newsItemLHR.title
  let message = newsItemLHR.message

  let payload = {
    notification: {
      title: 'LHR News',
      body: title,
      sound: 'default'
    }
  }

  console.log(payload)
  let topic = 'LHR'

  admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)

}
```

the 2 function are the same , what change is the topic and the matching name. I have 21 of the same. 
I am sure there is a better way to do it by detecting in firebase the content of the authenticated current user 's child called "base":  and using the value (FRA , CDG , ORD etc) to define the topic.  so I dont have to repeat the same function for each available base.
Hope I am not too confusing and I greatly appreciate any help. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple wildcards and take the value of the parameter to determine what to do.  For example, this is valid:

```
exports.news = functions.database
.ref('news/{x}/{uid}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  const x = context.params.x
  let newsItem = snapshot.val()
  sendNotification(x, newsItem)
})
```

Comment: i understand but what I lack knowledge of is how I pass in the "base" child value for the current app user to the {x}. doesn't context.params.x part of the news  ref in the realtime database? each children in the news database contains only a mid, messageTitle, messageBody, and umageUrl

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The ref just matches the path of the child written.  There is no "passing" of data.  It's just the value of the path segment, and the wildcard will match those path segments and becomes available in `context.params`.